# How to extract Device opened data in SFMC using SQL Query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, data-views

Currently on a daily basis we store email open/clicks etc. data in a data extension in SFMC and then export it to our data warehouse.

```
Example :
SELECT O.JobID, O.SubscriberID, O.EventDate, O.IsUnique, O.BatchID  
FROM _Open AS O
WHERE O.EventDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE))
AND O.EventDate < CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE)
```

Is it possible to modify this query to get the device information in which the email was opened? i,e Desktop or Mobile

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. This information is not stored in a Data View or any object that is accessible via SQL.

Longer answer is that inside of a Data Extract there is an option to get this information inside of the tracking extract - but be warned it is not all that accurate (as most of those trying to get this info are not) so it is more just to get a general idea than as an actionable metric. Utilizing Litmus or Email On Acid analytics for this type of thing would likely be better.

I believe there are also some reports that can get this info as well. Not positive though as have not explored Datorama Reports much yet.